# Ruby: using pack("n") with integers

Tags: ruby, integer, hex, pack, fixnum

I know that I need to use `[5].pack("n")` for example. This produces the output `"\x00\x05"`

But now I want to pack the length of a string. If I use:

```
"Hello".length.pack("n")
```

I get the error

```
undefined method `pack' for 5:Fixnum (NoMethodError).
```

How can I fix this? I've already tried to convert `"Hello".length` into an integer with `"Hello".length.to_i` but then I get the same error. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `["Hello".length].pack("n")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an array, not integer(`"Hello".length` is already one).

```
["Hello".length].pack("n")
# => "\x00\x05"
```

Comment: Stupid me... Thank you. Will accept the answer in 10 minutes^^